# c # please explain why this works ,

Tags: c#

I do not understand how this program works, If the original sum is set to `0` and then the `r(remainder)` is added to the sum which is `0`. How is that the correct sum of the two digits? I feel like it should look like this... `sum = num + r;`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Application
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            int num, sum = 0, r;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number : ");
            num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (num != 0)
            {
                r = num % 10;
                num = num / 10;
                **sum = sum + r;**
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Sum of Digits of the Number : "+sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `r` takes the digits from number. and add it to the sum. where is the confusion?

Comment: Welcome to [SO], please read the [FAQ]'s and [ask]. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i.e. `num` = **123**

1. `num` != 0 is true, then enter the `while`

   - `r` = `num` % 10 = 123 % 10 = **3**,
   - `num` = `num` / 10 = 123 / 10 = **12**,
   - `sum` = `sum` + `r` = 0 + 3 = **3**
2. `num` != 0 is true, then enter the `while`

   - `r` = `num` % 10 = 12 % 10 = **2**,
   - `num` = `num` / 10 = 12 / 10 = **1**,
   - `sum` = `sum` + `r` = 3 + 2 = **5**
3. `num` != 0 is true, then enter the `while`

   - `r` = `num` % 10 = 1 % 10 = **1**,
   - `num` = `num` / 10 = 1 / 10 = **0**,
   - `sum` = `sum` + `r` = 5 + 1 = **6**
4. `num` != 0 is false, then skip the `while`

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget that it's in a loop. `sum` is 0 on the first iteration, but on the *second* iteration it contains the value of the last digit.

So imagine you had a number of 195692. It would go through 7 iterations:

```
num      sum (before)   r    sum (after)
195692     0            2      2
 19569     2            9     11
  1956    11            6     17
   195    17            5     22
    19    22            9     31
     1    31            1     32
```

So the result is 32, which is 1 + 9 + 5 + 6 + 9 + 2.

Note that you could produce that table yourself by adding some diagnostic lines within the code... or you could produce it on pen and paper by debugging through the code to see how it works "live".

If you had `sum = r + num` that would be adding the last digit to the result of dividing the number by 10... and completely ignoring the previous sum.

Comment: Plus one for my Idol :)

Answer (score 1):

In the loop, the number decrements by one digit at a time from the right.

The steps are:

> r = num % 10

The percent symbol is modulus, which as you would be aware, this is the remainder of dividing the first number by the second number, which in the case of modulus 10 this is equal to the last digit.

> num = num / 10

This is a simple division, and since we are dealing with an integer (i.e. no decimal places) AND we are dividing by 10, then we lose the last digit.

> sum = sum + r

This adds the amount of the remainder to our total.

Lets say we start with the number num=987, then the iteration would work like thus:

> num = 987, r = 987 % 10 = 7, num = 987 / 10 = 98, sum = 0+7 = 7
>
> num = 98, r = 98 % 10 = 8, num = 98 / 10 = 9, sum = 7+8 = 15
>
> num = 9, r = 9 % 10 = 9, num = 9 / 10 = 0, sum = 15+9 = 24

So sum ends up being the equivalent of 0+7+8+9 = 24.

If you changed the summation line to sum = num + r, the iterations would be:

> sum = 98+7 = 105
>
> sum = 9+8 = 17
>
> sum = 0+9 = 9

Obviously this is not what you are after.